# NReco PdfGenerator customize output path c#

Tags: c#, pdf-generation, filepath

I'm using the free version of NReco to convert html to pdf. The pdf is downloaded in default folder "Downloads". I need to customize it. Can anyone help me?

Thanks!

**Edit:**
The code that downloads the pdf in default folder was:

```
var pdfBytes = pdfConverter.GeneratePdf(strHtml);
Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
Response.ContentEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;
Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=TEST.pdf");
Response.BinaryWrite(pdfBytes);
Response.TransmitFile(output_path_pdf);
Response.Flush();
Response.End();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solution don't downloads the PDF as an attachment, but downloads it directly in the selected path, and it solves my problem.

```
            string output_path_pdf = HttpContext.Server.MapPath("~/PDF_RESULT/" + fileName + ".pdf");
            HtmlToPdfConverter pdfConverter = new HtmlToPdfConverter();
            pdfConverter.PageWidth = 1000;
            pdfConverter.PageHeight = 800;
            pdfConverter.Margins = new PageMargins { Top = 0, Bottom = 0, Left = 0, Right = 0 };
            pdfConverter.GeneratePdfFromFiles(new string[] { URL }, null, output_path_pdf);
```